# Adding custom validation to a model in django

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-admin

I am using default admin views for performing CRUD operations for a model. I wanted to add a custom validation to my model with a certain logic. I want the default field validation like not null to be there but I also want to add a custom validation logic myself. When I add the clean function in my model, I could get to run my custom validation logic, but it doesn't run the default field validations like not null,empty etc.

I don't need to use Model forms, I am good with the admin generated forms. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your clean override a super call like this:

```
def clean(self):
    super(MyModule,self).clean()
    #do your validations
```

That way the module will do his normal validations and yours too.

Comment: `clean` is a `Form` class method, not `Model` however